# QWidget scroll bar for QPainter

Tags: c++, qt

Can anyone point me to the right solution please with the following issue:

Got a QWidget, which is drawing a grid (simple lines) with QPainter. The size is set on a separate form (e.g.: 1024*1024 px with grid lines every 64 pixel)

The task is to get a scrollbar on the widget if the drawn grid is greater than the parent display area.

```
ui->setupUi(this);
m_mapDisplay.setParent(this);
ui->loMapDisplay->addWidget(ui->scrollArea);
ui->scrollArea->setWidget(&m_mapDisplay);
ui->scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);
ui->scrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
ui->scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
```

Comment: Can't you just put your widget in a [`QScrollArea`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html)?

Comment: Please put code in the question rather than in comments.  Also, try setting the [scroll bar policy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop) for the vertical and/or horizontal scroll bars.

Comment: With ScrollBarAlwaysOn I can see them, but the drawing is not taken into account. Maybe I need to add the scrollArea to the widget itself, not the parent?

Comment: I've figured out if the minimumSize of the mapDisplay is set, than the scrollbars are displayed. The question now is how to set the minimumSize based on user selected values? (e.g.: 1024px 2048 px)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me was to use `setFixedSize(int x, int y)`